# error: cannot find symbol in ActionLearner

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, lambda, actionlistener

I am currently working on a GUI and I have an array of Jbutton. I also have another  array of information to insert specifically into each Jbutton. So when I press a button it will bring me to a new popup however I want the popup to print only the information specifically for that Jbutton. I am unsure how I can do it.  Below is a snippet of my script. Really hope there will be someone out there to help me with this. Pardon me as im not too sure how I can phrase it and if there is any doubt I can explain further. (the ** ic ** and ** s ** is meant to bold the two variables im not too sure why it is not bold)

```
jbArray = new JButton [pArray.length];
    for (int i = 0; i < pArray.length ; i++)
    {
        defaultpic = new ImageIcon("default.jpg");
        rolloverpic = new ImageIcon("coloured.jpg");

        jbArray[i]= new JButton (pArray[i].getbuttonName(),defaultpic);
        jbArray[i].setRolloverIcon(rolloverpic);
        add (jbArray[i]); 
    }

    // Register the events to each button 
    for (int i = 0; i < jbArray.length; i++)
    {
        jbArray[i].addActionListener (new SButtonClass (pArray[i].getbuttonName()));
        ImageIcon **ic** = pArray[i].getimageFile();
        String **s** = pArray[i].toString();    
    }
     //----------------------End of Student Buttons ----------------------
}

private class SButtonClass implements ActionListener{

    @Override 
    public void actionPerformed  (ActionEvent e)
    {
        if (e.getSource () == questionBox);

        String str = **s** + questionBox.getText();

        Icon studentdp = new ImageIcon (**ic**);

        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, str, "Welcome to Chat Room", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE, studentdp);
    }
}
```

update: I removed class SButtonclass and adjusted the new SButtonClass code to:

```
for (int i = 0; i < jbArray.length; i++)
{
        jbArray[i].addActionListener((e) -> {
            String str = pArray[i].toString() + questionBox.getText();
            Icon studentdp = new ImageIcon (pArray[i].getimageFile());
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, str, "Welcome to Chat Room", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE, studentdp);
        });
    }
```

however I face a new error: "local variables referenced from a lambda expression must be final or effectively final."
local variable referring to the i in this statement String str = pArray[i].toString() + questionBox.getText();

Comment: Who has taught you to name variables like `**ic**` and `**s**`? Follow [Java naming conventions](https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase/codeconventions-namingconventions.html).

Comment: Im sorry the ** was meant to bold it for this question

Comment: You will need `import java.awt.event.*;`, `import java.awt.event.ActionListener;` or change `ActionListener` to `java.awt.event.ActionListener` (oh, and same for `ActionEvent`). Alternatively, use a lambda expression.

Comment: Hi sir I have already imported java.awt.event.ActionListener. by any chance do you mind explaining more on lambda expression? @TomHawtin-tackline

Comment: @ApprenticeR The `new SButtonClass(...)` code and `SButtonClass` itself could be reaplced with `e -> { /* body of actionListener */  }`. I also notice that you are passing an argument to the `SButtonClass` but there is no appropriate constructor.

Comment: @TomHawtin-tackline Hi sir,  I have taken your advice and replace the new SButtonClass(...) code and SButtonClass with lambda. However I face a new error however I face an error -  "local variables referenced from a lambda expression must be final or effectively final"

Comment: "Im sorry the ** was meant to bold it" There is a preview shown below, when posting a question, and an [edit] link below left of the question, to update it at any time. (Please make use of them rather than offer apologies.)

Comment: @ApprenticeR That will be the `i` variable - by the time the `ActionListener` will have fired the loop will have exited and `i` will have moved on to `jbArray.length`. The easiest fix would to add an (affectively final) local `TypeOfP p = pArray[i];` outside of the lambda but inside the for loop, then replace the references to `pArray[i]` with `p` within the lambda. That should also be easier to follow.